# Exporting HSQLDB database with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: java, utf-8, hsqldb, geotools

I'm trying to export the GeoTools HSQL 2 database and load it back into HSQL 1 for a legacy system that needs the older database format.  The tables include characters like the degree symbol.  However, it's coming out as the escape sequence `\u0080` rather the encoded character.  I need to either fix that or have HSQL 1 import convert the escaped characters back into the correct encoding.

e.g.

```
cp modules/plugin/epsg-hsql/src/main/resources/org/geotools/referencing/factory/epsg/EPSG.zip /tmp
cd /tmp
unzip EPSG.zip
java -jar hsqldb-2.4.1.jar 
# For the file, put jdbc:hsqldb:file:/tmp/EPSG
SELECT 'epsg-dump'
```

And in the results I see things like this `\u00b5`:

```
INSERT INTO EPSG_ALIAS VALUES(389,'epsg_unitofmeasure',9109,7302,'\u00b5rad','')
```

Looking into hsqldb, I'm not sure how to control the encoding the of the data being written, assuming that this is the correct location to look:

https://github.com/ryenus/hsqldb/blob/master/src/org/hsqldb/scriptio/ScriptWriterText.java

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following procedure:

1. In the source database, create TEXT tables with exactly the same columns as the original tables. Use `CREATE TEXT TABLE thecopyname (LIKE thesourcename)` for each table.
2. Use `SET TABLE thecopyname SOURCE 'thecopyname.csv;encoding=UTF-8'` for each of the `copy` tables.
3. INSERT into each `thecopyname` table with `SELECT * FROM thesourcename`.
4. Use `SET TABLE thecopyname SOURCE OFF` for each `thecopyname`
5. You will now have several `thecopyname.csv` files (each with its own name) with UTF8 encoding.
6. Use the reverse procedure on the target database. You need to explicity create the TEXT tables then use `SET TABLE thecopyname SOURCE 'thecopyname.csv;encoding=UTF-8'`

Comment: I'm having trouble with the mechanics of doing this from the UI, so I've asked a follow up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54357312/how-to-do-multiple-commands-one-execute-in-the-hsqldb-gui

Answer (score 1):

The encoding looks like Unicode (one to four hex digits).
Try this in `bash` (quick & dirty):

`echo -ne "$(< dump.sql)" > dump_utf8.sql`

Comment: Can you explain that please?

Comment: `$(< dumpl.sql)` reads the sql dump (bash command substitution, same as `$(cat dump.sql)`). 
The output is echoed interpreting the unicode backslash escaped characters (option -e) and without a trailing newline (option -n).
The echoed result is then redirected to file dump_utf8.sql.

I'm assuming your system is running in default locale UTF-8, to verify it use `echo $LANG` in your bash shell, thus resulting in a valid UTF-8 encoded sql dump.

Comment: This is a very cool trick, but it gets tripped up with \u000a getting turned into a new line.