# How to do multiple commands one execute in the HSQLDB GUI?

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I have a number of command that I want to do from the GUI.  I want to do many groups of these, but I can't get a single group to work.  I presume I need to somehow force commits between them, but I can't figure out how to do that.  If I execute each one of these commands by itself in order, everything works as expected.

I'm using the `EPSG.dat` from GeoTools' EPSG.zip.

```
unzip EPSG.zip
perl -pi -e 's/readonly=true/readonly=false/' EPSG.properties

java -jar hsqldb-2.4.1.jar
jdbc:hsqldb:file:./EPSG

SET AUTOCOMMIT true;  -- Press Execute SQL, but this doesn't seem to help.

CREATE TEXT TABLE EPSG_UNITOFMEASURE_COPY (LIKE EPSG_UNITOFMEASURE);                                                      
GRANT all ON  EPSG_UNITOFMEASURE_COPY TO public;                                                                          
SET TABLE EPSG_UNITOFMEASURE_COPY SOURCE 'EPSG_UNITOFMEASURE_COPY.csv;encoding=UTF-8';                                    
INSERT INTO EPSG_UNITOFMEASURE_COPY SELECT * FROM EPSG_UNITOFMEASURE;                                                     
SET TABLE EPSG_UNITOFMEASURE_COPY SOURCE OFF;
```

I then get an error of:

```
user lacks privilege or object not found: EPSG_UNITOFMEASURE_COPY / Error Code: -5501 / State: 42501
```

I am pretty sure this is an `object not found` case.

Comment: This is a follow up to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54208286/exporting-hsqldb-database-with-utf-8-encoding/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute these commands as one block. When a schema definition statement refers to a schema object, that object must already exist.

Execute the CREATE TEXT TABLE, then you can execute the rest as a block.

Comment: It looks like FOO.script and pasting commands in the execute window of the UI behave totally differently.  So confusing.